# How to transform lscpu output to JSON format?

Tags: bash, json, lscpu

I've had to deal with case I need the JSON format data of `lscpu` output, but `-J` key hasn't supported.

So I made simple command line script allows to transform plain output to JSON which I'll post here as an answer.

Comment: Is the issue that some older systems may have a `lscpu` release that does not support JSON output? If so, I expect that you want to parse the `lscpu` command's output and convert it to the same type of structure as `lscpu -J` gives you?  Can you give examples of the `lscpu` output and the corresponding JSON structure?

Comment: @Kusalananda Where can I post example? Would it good enough to post the output at the answer I print below?

Comment: Well, since any answer would depend on what the input looks like and what the output should look like, adding examples of input and output to the question would be best.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've edited answer where I added initial output and then output  formatted as JSON.
Is that what was lack?

Comment: @Aleksey example input should be in the question, and it should also include the desired output for that input.

Comment: @muru Should I transport all section from `console log` line to the question body?

Comment: @Aleksey yes, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo {$(lscpu | sed 's/  */ /g' | sed 's/: /:/g' | awk -F ':' '{print "\x22"$1"\x22: \x22"$2"\x22,"}') | sed 's/,$/}/'
```

Two `sed` remove extra spaces, `awk` creates double quotes around the fields and last `sed` replace last comma by brace encloses the array created by the first brace.

console log:

```
lscpu

Architecture:                    aarch64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
Vendor ID:                       ARM
Model:                           3
Model name:                      Cortex-A72
Stepping:                        r0p3
CPU max MHz:                     1800.0000
CPU min MHz:                     600.0000
BogoMIPS:                        108.00
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Vulnerable
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Vulnerable
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid

-----------------------------------------------------------

echo {$(lscpu | sed s/ automation/ snap/ /g | sed s/: /:/g | awk -F : {print "": "",}) | sed s/,$/}/

{
  "Architecture": "aarch64",
  "CPU op-mode(s)": "32-bit, 64-bit",
  "Byte Order": "Little Endian",
  "CPU(s)": "4",
  "On-line CPU(s) list": "0-3",
  "Thread(s) per core": "1",
  "Core(s) per socket": "4",
  "Socket(s)": "1",
  "Vendor ID": "ARM",
  "Model": "3",
  "Model name": "Cortex-A72",
  "Stepping": "r0p3",
  "CPU max MHz": "1800.0000",
  "CPU min MHz": "600.0000",
  "BogoMIPS": "108.00",
  "Vulnerability Itlb multihit": "Not affected",
  "Vulnerability L1tf": "Not affected",
  "Vulnerability Mds": "Not affected",
  "Vulnerability Meltdown": "Not affected",
  "Vulnerability Mmio stale data": "Not affected",
  "Vulnerability Spec store bypass": "Vulnerable",
  "Vulnerability Spectre v1": "Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization",
  "Vulnerability Spectre v2": "Vulnerable",
  "Vulnerability Srbds": "Not affected",
  "Vulnerability Tsx async abort": "Not affected",
  "Flags": "fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid"
}
```

Comment: note you can reduce your process count by replacing your 2 intial `sed` cmds with `gsub(...)` cmds inside your  `awk` script. I'll upvote your answer if you make those changes OR include them as an alternate solution. [Awk Tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) will help .

Comment: Also, if this is your answer, you should mark it as such, even if it's your own answer.  That is allowed.